# Some Data Unaccounted For When Iterating Over Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on a random exercise from my C++ book because I'm "re-learning" C++, but I'm getting some odd output from a program I wrote. I'm fairly certain there are no errors in the logic of the program, but where the sum of the elements in the "scoreCount" array should be 26, the same as the length of the scores array, it is only 20. I can't figure out what happened to the other 6 elements. The description of the exercise is in the code below. Can anyone spot what I might have done wrong?

```
/* Exercise 09 - 04

   Write a program that reads a file consisting of students' test scores
   in the range 0-200. It should then determine the number of students having
   scores in each of the following ranges: 0-24, 25-49, 50-74, 75-99,
   100-124, 125-149, 150-174, and 175-200. Output the score ranges and the
   number of students. (Run your program with the following input data:
   76, 89, 150, 135, 200, 76, 12, 100, 150, 28, 178, 189, 167, 200, 175,
   150, 87, 99, 129, 149, 176, 200, 87, 35, 157, 189.) */
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  int scores[] = {76, 89, 150, 135, 200, 76, 12, 100, 150, 28, 178, 189,
                  167, 200, 175, 150, 87, 99, 129, 149, 176, 200, 87,
                  35, 157, 189};
  int size = sizeof(scores) / sizeof(scores[0]);
  int scoreCount[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

  printf("Number of Scores: %d\n\n", size);

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    scoreCount[((int)(scores[i]/25))] += 1;
    printf("%d - scoreCount Index: %d\n", i, ((int)(scores[i]/25)));
  }

  printf("\n");

  int low = 0;
  int high = 24;

  size = sizeof(scoreCount) / sizeof(scoreCount[0]);

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("Range %d-%d: %d\n", low, high, scoreCount[i]);
    low += 25;
    high += 25;
    if(high == 199) high = 200;
  }

  int sum = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sum += scoreCount[i];
  }

  if(sum < 26) printf("\n%d: Wrong number of scores counted.\n", sum);
  else printf("\nAll students accounted for.\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Most likely indexing out of range for `scoreCount`

Comment: Scores of 200 / 25 = 8 which would be an invalid index for scoreCount.

Comment: Start learning C++ using C io instead of C++ io is a good practice?

Comment: @Manu343726 I've added a gratuitous answer doing just that

Comment: I said I'm "re-learning". And besides, I know that's not standard C++, but I'm not a fan of the "cout" syntax. I prefer using functions and placeholders.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau Well either get used to it or make your own variadic `fprintf` to sanitise your dislike for streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  scoreCount[((int)(scores[i]/25))] += 1;
```

This would produce 8 if score[i] is 200. And currently your code does not handle this.

Comment: I use Java on a regular basis, so at first I thought how this code would even run, it should throw some Exception(something like ArrayIndexOutOfBound in Java), then realize it is c++, which doesn't bothers about crossing index element of array.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of this. I'm primarily a Java programmer as well and expected an error if something like this were to happen.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau which is what the comment to use C++ style (which is more highlevel) was completely warranted. See my answer. Note how my answer doesn't worry about sizes or indices. Instead it writes intent.

Comment: cmon @Algorithmist. atleast you should format your post properly

Comment: @Saksham 10x for the Edit :).

Answer (score 7):

Here's proper C++ style. I know the question has already been answered, but here's a bonus:

See it live on **http://ideone.com/rBTi42**

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    const std::vector<int> scores = {76, 89, 150, 135, 200, 76, 12, 100, 150, 28, 178, 189,
                                     167, 200, 175, 150, 87, 99, 129, 149, 176, 200, 87,
                                     35, 157, 189
                                    };
    std::map<int, int> scoreCount;
    std::cout << "Number of Scores: " << scores.size() << "\n";

    for(auto score : scores)
    {
        scoreCount[score/25] ++;
        std::cout <<  score << " - scoreCount Index: " << score/25 << "\n";
    }

    for(auto const& slot : scoreCount)
    {
        auto low  = slot.first*25;
        auto high = low+24;
        std::cout << "Range " << low << "-" << high << ": " << slot.second << "\n";
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for(auto const& slot : scoreCount)
        sum += slot.second;

    if(sum < 26)
        printf("\n%d: Wrong number of scores counted.\n", sum);
    else
        printf("\nAll students accounted for.\n");
}
```

Comment: I know proper C++ style, but I'm not a fan of the "cout" syntax. I prefer using functions. I'll use it when it's needed.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau its not just using streams for outputs, is using the multitude of built in data structures. This code is more clear than yours, doesn't have subtle and dangerous issues like out-of-bounds array access hiding. You can replace the cout with printf, but maps a vectors add robustness in this case.

Comment: This is the good answer. This is C++ code. iostream and a correct use of std::map

Comment: C++ is not getting a C style and put `class` instead of `struct`. C++ is raw-pointer-less code, STL algorithms/containers based code, and high level io.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau the cout is immaterial, IMO, allthough you'd probably have a hard time telling whether %d, %i, %lu or whatnot would apply for `scores.size()`. Which is, actually, **exactly** the only reason I opted out of `printf` (I like `printf`, Boost Format, fastformat etc. libraries)

Comment: By the way, just replacing the C-style array with `std::array` and using `scoreCount.at(scores[i]/25) += 1;` would have closed the bug opportunity already: http://ideone.com/hdnRYx throws  'std::out_of_range' /cc @Algorithmist. That's modifying 2 lines

Comment: Also, is this C++11? I'm still using C++98. I'm pretty sure C++98 doesn't have a for-each syntax or an auto keyword.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau Hmm? Here's c++03 versions [using just tr1::array](http://ideone.com/lmq26i), or [using vector and map](http://ideone.com/f2Mxg6), and [using both](http://ideone.com/ifp0NC). Take note of the helpers to do safe `begin()`, `end()` and `arr_size()` on C-style arrays. Everything live, online compiled and running on gcc 4.3.2

Comment: And in _return trolling_ C++ has has had the `auto` keyword since before standardization :/

Answer (score 1):

The number of elements should be 9 rather than 8 in the scoreCount array.

As 200/25 will be evaluated to 8 and it results in index out of bound

**EDIT:**

As suggested by  Andrew_CS, the element having value as 200 shoud be added to the last group itself.

```
scoreCount[(scores[i]/25)==8?7:(scores[i]/25)] += 1;
```

Comment: Do you mean 9 rather than 8?  `scoreCount` currently requires indices [0..8], so 9 elements.

Comment: There are 8 indexes which is correct because there are 8 score groups.

Comment: Adding another element fixes the index out of bounds error, however the problem calls for 8 different groups of scores, not 9.  If you add another element to handle the case of 200/25 = 8 then that index in scoreCounts needs to be combined with index 7 since they both belong to the same score group of 175-200.  A better approach might  be checking if the index equates to 8, if so then add to index 7 instead.

Comment: consider `scoreCount[std::min(7, scores[i]/25)] += 1`

Answer (score 1):

200 / 25 = 8 and 
scoreCount[8] does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You are generating an index out of bounds for `scoreCount` here:

```
scoreCount[((int)(scores[i]/25))] += 1;
```

The valid indexes for `scoreCount` are from `0 to 7` but with your current `scores` you will generate indexes up to `8`. A solution would be to extend `scoreCount` by one element or to check if the index is `8` and map it to index `7` since it seems like the problem limits your ranges.

Comment: Rather than extend the scoreCount array, I opted to subtract 1 from the index and put it in the previous one, since 200 is not its own range in the problem, and falls in the range of 175-200.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau Yep, that makes sense, after rereading the problem I realized you were limited in your ranges allowed and so I updated my answer to add that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code on my machine.
I got 23 out of 26.

The reason for this is that there are 3 values of 200. 
When the value is 200 the it will be under 8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the number of elements in the `scoreCount` array because `200/25` gives `8` and `scoreCount[8]` does not exists .

Comment: Rather than increase the size of that array, I just subtracted 1 from the index when the score is 200 so that it goes in the previous element since 200 falls in the 175-200 range, and is not in itself a range.

Answer (score 0):

200/25 = 8 is out of bounds for scoreCount - only has indexes 0 - 7.

I personally wouldn't increase the number of elements in scoreCount since there are only 8 groups of valid scores.  I would instead check for this one case that produces 8 as an index.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    int theIndex = (scores[i]/25);
    if(theIndex == 8)
        scoreCount[7] += 1;
    else
        scoreCount[theIndex] += 1;
    printf("%d - scoreCount Index: %d\n", i, theIndex;
}
```